# Finding one eigenvalue for a large matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am currently solving a previous exam and I came upon this question:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
        3 & 2 & -3 & 1 & 0 \\
        2 & 5 & -2 & 0 & 3 \\
        -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -2 \\
        2 & 2 & -2 & -1 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
Determine one eigenvalue of this matrix. Now obviously, solving it using the traditional method(i.e. det(A-lambdaI)=0) would take me most of the test. So, is there a trick involved here or a simpler method? Thanks in advance.

Found the answer: The first and third columns can be written as one another, meaning that the matrix is linearly dependent. So the determinant is 0 making the only eigenvalue 0. Credit to the guys/gals in the comments below.

Off-Topic question: I am solving many previous exams which unfortunately lack solutions, so I cannot verify my answers. Is it acceptable if I post links to these exams or perhaps links to snapshots of specific questions or is it preferable to post them like this because it would take a lot of time.

Comment: Hint: Consider the first and third columns.

Comment: Hint : The determinant must be $0$

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting somewhere, so since the first and third columns can be written as one another, the matrix is linearly dependent, meaning that the determinant is 0 and that relates somehow to the eigenvalue. Ah I checked, since the determinant is 0, so the only eigenvalue is 0. Thanks a lot guys.

And just in case you know: Do you think it would be acceptable to post entire questions(i.e. imgur links to snapshots of these questions)?

Comment: $(1,0,1,0,0) $ is an eigenvector with zero as eigenvalue.

Comment: Abdallah, I have found the answer but I want to know how you got those numbers, did you reduce the matrix?

Comment: Nah, once you found $0$ to be an eigenvalue, it is really not that hard to find an eigenvector, using the definition

Comment: @HadiNounou $0$ need not be the ONLY eigenvalue, but it must be one of the eigenvalues.